# Getting randomly ordered output from ordered list

Tags: python

For an online assignment to be submitted for a MOOC, I have written a python program that takes in text data (The name, roll numbers, grades, etc of a list of students) in a particular format and prints the output after processing the data. The output is printed from a list of tuples using a for loop to iterate through the list and using the `str.join()` function to join the elements in the tuples. 
The list of tuples is sorted already and when I run it in the *Spyder* IDE console, it prints the output in the order that it appears in the list. But, when I submit in the window of the online judge and run it, the output is obtained in a random order and my answer doesn't get accepted. Can anyone please help? I am all ready to clarify further if my question isn't clear.
Thank you.

Comment: You are better off with showing your code here, I think. My guess is that you rely on sorted input for your function and the online judge uses same data sorted differently as input.

Comment: @EPo Thank you very much. That was exactly the problem. I tested it with sorted input. Adding a "sorted(list)" did the job. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Epo rightly pointed out, I tested my input with alphabetically sorted data while the online judge used the same data sorted differently as input. Adding a "sorted()" function to the input did the job.